# Flash GUI Interface Hud

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, user-interface, interface, hud

I would like to create a main menu and a hud within the application that stores and displays user information. Buttons like sound and main menu options should exist..

Now i cant seem to find any examples of how to create this user interface / hud.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Thanks,

CS4
AS3

Answer (score 1):

You may find The [MinimalComps](http://code.google.com/p/minimalcomps/) project interesting.

[See it in action](http://www.minimalcomps.com/).

Answer (score 1):

So this question is basically "How do I make buttons, and have those buttons do things when clicked?". I suggest starting with some basic Flash tutorials. Maybe buy a book on it, there's lots of them out there.

Comment: No that wasnt the question at all. I am after creating a HUD with a display area, controls etc. Im wondering the correct method to do this as there seems to be a number of different methods.

Answer (score 0):

You may find The [miniui](http://code.google.com/p/actionscriptiui/) project interesting.

Comment: Should this be a comment? Lone link is bad.